# Adding a variable to a ts object in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have an object that I have created using the `as.ts` function in R, and now I would like a simple way to transform one of the variables and add it to the same `ts` object. So, for example

```
tsMloa <- ts(read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/mloa.dta"), frequency=12, start=1959)
tsMloa[, "meanLog"] <- tsMloa[,"log"] - mean(tsMloa[,"log"])
```

gives me a `subscript out of bounds` error. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you ought to consider adding `require(foreign)` to your example code, as it's necessary to run your code.

I don't know anything about `*.dta` files or their formatting, but i can tell you that if you'd like to work with time series in `R`, you'd do well to look into the `zoo` and `xts` family of functions.

With that in mind, try the following:

```
require(xts)
require(foreign)

tsMloa <- ts(read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/mloa.dta"), frequency=12, start=1959)

tt <- seq(as.Date("1959-01-01"), as.Date("1990-12-01"), by='mon')
tsMloa_x <- xts(unclass(tsMloa)[,1:3], order.by=tt)

tsMloa_x$meanLog <- tsMloa_x$log - mean(tsMloa_x$log)
```

That should do what you are looking for -- and it gives you a reason to look into the very good packages.

---

Doing it with `zoo` -- plus i've created a function to turn your integers into months.

```
require(foreign)
require(zoo)

Mloa <- read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/mloa.dta"), frequency=12, start=1959)

intToMonth <- function(intMonth, origin = "1960-01-01"){
    dd <- as.POSIXlt(origin)
    ddVec <- rep(dd, length(intMonth))
    ddVec$mon  <- ddVec$mon + intMonth%%12
    ddVec$year <- ddVec$year + intMonth%/%12
    ddRet <- as.Date(ddVec)
    return(ddRet)
}

dateString <- intToMonth(Mloa[, 'tm'])

zMloa <- zoo(Mloa[, -2], dateString)
zMloa$meanLog <- zMloa$log - mean(zMloa$log)
```

As i see it, your problem is with converting the timestamps in the source file to something R understands and can work with. I found this part of adapting to R especially tricky.

The above function will take your month-integers, and turn them into a `Date` object. The resultant output will work with both `zoo` and `xts` as the `order.by` argument.

If you need to change the origin date, just supply the second argument to the function -- i.e. `otherDateString <- intToMonth(timeInts, "2011-01-01")`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to convert the object read in using `read.dta` directly into an `xts` object?
`dfMloa <- as.data.frame(read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/mloa.dta", convert.dates=T))` to read it in as a `data.frame` and then `xts(dfMloa, order.by=as.Date(dfMloa$tm))`? This does not give me the right dates, however.

Comment: @fgnu: `read.dta` already returns a data.frame; no need to wrap it in `as.data.frame`.  xts requires that the index be a date-time class and `tm` is just a number, so it won't work (that's why @ricardo created `tt`).  zoo does not have this requirement, so you could use `zmloa <- zoo(mloa[,-2], mloa$tm)`, where `mloa` is the result from the `read.dta` function.

Comment: @fg nu -- i think your problem here is getting the date conversion details just right in R. I find this tricky as well.  I have written a little function that will convert integers that are mapped to months to dates that R can work with.

Comment: @ricardo Thank you again for your help. The function is great and I intend to use it :) but what I can't understand is what the `convert.dates=TRUE` in the `read.dta` function does. Stata (it of the `.dta` format) internally represents dates as integers with a fixed origin reference (which is precisely the understanding your function makes use of). I would have thought that `convert.dates`  would be converting to some sort of POSIX based dates. Can't tell if this is the case at all. If you can comment on this issue, that would be great, but if not, many thanks for your excellent help.

Comment: sorry, i don't know much about the `foreign` package. I'm sure if you ask another question about how it all works, someone might know.